# Adding google maps library to existing project creates confusing error

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I am building an Android app that I want to open google maps with the click of a button. I want the app to find the current location of the user and give them directions to a predefined address. I started building the application before I realized there were special steps that you have to take to include this functionality. To add this feature to my project I followed the directions on these two sites:

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

The problem is on the second site, when i added the library to my already existing project it caused all of my code that has **findViewById(R.id.whatever)** or **setContentView(R.layout.whatever)** to become errors. It is now telling me that i need to import the class R. If I do that it then gives me error messages on the names of all my xml files.

For example in my MainActivity it is telling me that i should change **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)** to **setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item)** and does this for all references to my xml files for the entire project.

I tried going back and removing the google play services library from the project and starting over but when I removed it the errors still persists. I also tried using the "fix project setup" option in Eclipse but it didn't fix the problem.

I'm wondering if anyone here has experienced this problem before? If so, how can I fix it? The application had no errors before I tried to include the google play services library. I am new to Android development so a lot of the information I have found has been either confusing to understand or doesn't seem to include enough details for me to figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You likely have an error in one of the files inside the res folder. If that happens, R cannot be imported in the code.

Comment: Found it, thank you! I had placed all my <uses-permission> tags AFTER the <application> tag in the manifest and they should be placed BEFORE. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `imports`, and check if you are importing the correct `R.java` from your application `package`, not from the android `package`.

Check also if your `XML`s don't contain errors, otherwise `R.java` won't be generated.

In my case `android-maps-library` had to errors in two files (I have forgotten their names), I edited the two files removing errors my self. And finally I was able to used it quite nice.

Comment: Thank you! I commented above how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have correct yout Project build target, and this how:
right click on your project folder in the package explorer->propreties->Android

then porject build target and choose you Android target (Android x.xx)

but before that you need to remove import android.R;